# The non-generic type 'ActionResult' cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I writing webAPI controller and try to get all values from DB

Here is Reminder class:

```
public class Reminder
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public DateTime RemindDate { get; set; }

    public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public bool IsCancelled { get; set; }
}
```

And there is controoller code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<List<Reminder>> GetAll()
{
    return _context.TodoItems.ToList();
}
```

I get this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0308  The non-generic type 'ActionResult' cannot be used with type arguments  RemindersApi    C:\Users\nemes\Source\Repos\GlobalMediatorTest\RemindersApi\RemindersApi\Controllers\ReminderController.cs  29  Active

How I can fix this?

Comment: are you using ASP.NET Core 2.1 or higher?

Comment: What do you want us to tell you that the error message hasn't already?

Comment: `ActionResult<T>` is available in .NET Core 2.1, nowhere else (at the moment).

Comment: I use ASP.NET core 2.1 @SamvelPetrosov

Comment: @EugeneSukh if you have connected asp.net core 2.1 to the project then try to clean and rebuild the project. Otherwise, this error message shows that you are not using asp.net core 2.1.

Comment: Okay, if I not use it, how I can switch to it? @SamvelPetrosov

Comment: @EugeneSukh https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/06/04/how-to-install-asp-net-core-2-1-for-development/

Comment: Thank's will check now@SamvelPetrosov

Comment: Yeah, I run 2.0 version, thanks @SamvelPetrosov

Answer (score 3):

So with help of @SamvelPetrosov I was able to see, that problem in version of SDK

I need to update to Core 2.1 version

Here is link to how to do this

[Tutuorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/06/04/how-to-install-asp-net-core-2-1-for-development/)